# How does one display an image from a collection of canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, collections

Start with

```
x = document.getElementsByTagName('CANVAS');
```

The return for x[n] is [object HTMLCanvasElement].

[Display Content of a List Item](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementsbytagname)

Displaying the content of a list item can be accomplished with innerHTML, but I've been unable to find an example in which the content of of a canvas item is displayed.

How does one access the content of x[n] to display the canvas?

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, you are trying to get the image drawn on canvas. However note that a canvas element in HTML is populated by a script, rather than what's between the `<canvas></canvas>` tags. My approach would be to get the canvas element from the array, append it somewhere in the document. Then to retrieve the content of the canvas, you run the script. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: @AgataB, You're correct. That's what I'm trying to do. I believe a collection behaves - or misbehaves - differently than an array. I have a working understanding of Image & dataURL, but canvas doesn't render the same way. You're heading me in the right direction informing that a canvas element is populated by a script. But, how do I access the script?

Comment: Script is usually inside the `<script> ... </script>` tags, but at this point it may be easier/quicker/simpler to just store the canvas as their image data? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp It depends on where you're getting the array from. The `<script> ... </script>` may contain a bunch of other stuff that's irrelevant.

Comment: You can get the image data using [getImageData()](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp) and set that on another canvas element. Or you can get the data as a data URL using [toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) on the canvas element. You can then use that as the src of an Image element, or open it in another window, etc.

Comment: ManoDestra, For the reason I explain below to @markE, toDataURL() doesn't work. I haven't tried getImageData(), yet, but it might work since the command is fetching already existent data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample HTML file showing various different methods of outputting the data in question. I've shown how to get data from a hidden canvas, but you could easily have it taken from an instantiated canvas element, or an array of them. I've shown how to copy canvas data to another canvas, to an image, to a new window/tab and to the console:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Canvas Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script>
            var canvas;
            var canvasHidden;
            var img;
            var ctxHidden;
            var ctx;

            function init() {
                console.log('init');
                canvasHidden = document.getElementById('canvasHidden');
                canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                img = document.getElementById('img');
                ctxHidden = canvasHidden.getContext('2d');
                var imgToLoad = new Image();
                imgToLoad.onload = function(event) {
                    ctxHidden.drawImage(event.target, 0, 0, canvasHidden.width, canvasHidden.height);
                };
                imgToLoad.src = "Example.jpg";

                canvas.width = canvasHidden.width;
                canvas.height = canvasHidden.height;
                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            }

            function toCanvas() {
                ctx.putImageData(ctxHidden.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height), 0, 0);
            }

            function toImage() {
                img.src = canvasHidden.toDataURL();
            }

            function toTab() {
                window.open(canvasHidden.toDataURL());
            }

            // Warning: this can take quite some time depending on the size of your image.
            // You may wish to only show limited pixel data, depending on your needs.
            function toConsole() {
                // Show all data on the console...
                var data1 = ctxHidden.getImageData(0, 0, canvasHidden.width, canvasHidden.height).data;
                console.log(data1);

                // Or just a single pixel (can easily be amended to display a small range of pixels instead)...
                var x = 32;
                var y = 25;
                var data2 = ctxHidden.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                for (var i = 0; i < data2.length; i += 4) {
                    console.log('Pixel data at [' + x + ', ' + y + ']:', data2[i], data2[i + 1], data2[i + 2], data2[i + 3]);
                }
            }

            window.onload = init;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvasHidden" style="display:none;"></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <img id="img" src="" alt="Will receive image data">
        <br>
        <button onclick="toCanvas();">To Canvas</button>
        <button onclick="toImage();">To Image</button>
        <button onclick="toTab();">To Tab</button>
        <button onclick="toConsole();">To Console</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Info on getImageData here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp

Info on toDataURL here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL